# Store and retrieve points monthly, quarterly and yearly

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have created an application using aws, and the database is aws dynamodb. there is a functionality in app for users to gain points by completing an activity. when admin verifies whether the user has done the activity, then he/she will receive the point. I need to make a functionality in which the admin can retrieve the points of users between two dates like, monthly, quarterly, and yearly. can anyone help me to implement this.

Currently i'm logging in every activity points entry in the table, but to read and produce the results will make the app costly.

Comment: If the date ranges are arbitrary (e.g. 17th of January through 23rd of May) then this idea won't work, but if they're just monthly, quarterly, and yearly per user then consider aggregating them via DynamoDB Streams. When a points-generating item is put, updated or deleted, DDB Streams could trigger a Lambda function that would update the aggregated totals for that user either in the same table (single table design) or in another table. Item keys for the aggregations could be pk=agg#user#<userid>, sk=YYYYMM (for monthly), sk=YYYYQ3 (for 3rd quarter), sk=YYYY (for annual).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create a GSI with your date as SK and PK as hardcoded common value. Let's call it `DateIndex`. So as an example you would have entry with PK=DateIndex and SK=2022-11-06T16:36:16.

With that you can make queries using `begins_with`. So you can use one query to get data for whole month or a day. Or create multiple queries to take data for lets say a week. Based on your case that could me seven daily queries joined on the application level. Or one bigger query fetching data from a whole month, and filter out the unnecessary data. Second is cleaner to implement since you don't need any application logic, but more expensive. Since you pay for the filtered out data